# How to stop php script from exiting itself

Tags: php, terminal, telegram-bot, termux

Am writing a simple telegram bot in php using getUpdates method for receiving messages from bot.
So after executing `php bot.php` in terminal, it works and reply only once then the script auto exit.

`bot.php`

```
<?php

 for ($i= 0; $i >0; $i++) {

/**

 * Telegram Bot whitout WebHook.

 * It uses getUpdates Telegram's API

 */

include 'Telegram.php'; //am using a php telegram bot Library

$bot_token = 'xyz';

$telegram = new Telegram($bot_token);

// Get all the new updates and set the new correct update_id

$req = $telegram->getUpdates();

for ($i = 0; $i < $telegram->UpdateCount(); $i++) {

    // You NEED to call serveUpdate before accessing the values of message in Telegram Class

    $telegram->serveUpdate($i);

    $text = $telegram->Text();

    $chat_id = $telegram->ChatID();

    if ($text == '/start') {

        $reply = 'Working';

        $content = ['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $reply];

        $telegram->sendMessage($content);

    }

    if ($text == '/test') {

        if ($telegram->messageFromGroup()) {

            $reply = 'Chat Group';

        } else {

            $reply = 'Private Chat';

        }

        

    

    if ($text == '/git') {

        $reply = 'Check me on GitHub: https://github.com/Eleirbag89/TelegramBotPHP';

        // Build the reply array

        $content = ['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $reply];

        $telegram->sendMessage($content);

 

    }

}

}
```

I tried setting `set_time_limit(0)` but it doesn't works, then I wrapped the entire code in a for loop. But it still exit after running once.
I want the script to remain running and reply all incoming messages, untill I exit script myself or exit terminal)

Comment: `while (true) {..}`

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here.

First, this outer loop will never do anything, because you set $i to zero and then run the loop only while $i is greater than zero... which it never is:

```
for ($i= 0; $i >0; $i++) {
```

Then you use the same variable for another loop inside that outer loop:

```
for ($i= 0; $i >0; $i++) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $telegram->UpdateCount(); $i++) {
```

So you've got $i trying to do two different things at once. If you're using nested loops, you want to use a different variable for each loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 100; $j++) {
```

If you want to wrap your whole script in a never-ending loop, you can do that most simply with:

```
while (true) {
    // your code here
}
```

There's no need to run the import each time, so I would put this wrapper just before the getUpdates() call:

```
while (true) {
    $req = $telegram->getUpdates();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $telegram->UpdateCount(); $i++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note this means your script will *never* exit. You'll have to hit control-c or kill its process. If you want the script to exit on some trigger, you can just break at the end of the loop:

```
while (true) {
    $req = $telegram->getUpdates();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $telegram->UpdateCount(); $i++) {
        // ...
    }
    if ($someCondition) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It really healed my code like a healing elixir. As for the while loop, if for some reason a function couldn't complete it's work like file_get_contents(), due to network issues. The code will still exit itself.